# I can't get the index of a string in an array and remove it | javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to Javascript and am making a memory game but i can't seem to get this code to work. What i am trying to do is choose a random element from my `ids` array and then remove it from that array but be able to use that value afterwards to assign it to an element in the cards array. What I came up with so far is this (updated):

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".memory-card");

let ids = ["1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6"];

function idHandler() {
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * ids.length);
    let x = ids.splice(rand, 1)[0];
    cards[x].setAttribute("id", x);
}

cards.forEach(mapIds);
```

Since someone asked for the html elements:

```
<div class="memory-card" id="1">
    <img src="../assets/turned.png" class="front-face">
</div>
<div class="memory-card" id="1">
    <img src="../assets/turned.png" class="front-face">
</div>
<div class="memory-card" id="2">
    <img src="../assets/turned.png" class="front-face">
</div>
<div class="memory-card" id="2">
    <img src="../assets/turned.png" class="front-face">
</div>
<div class="memory-card" id="3">
    <img src="../assets/turned.png" class="front-face">
</div>
<div class="memory-card" id="3">
    <img src="../assets/turned.png" class="front-face">
</div>
<div class="memory-card" id="4">
    <img src="../assets/turned.png" class="front-face">
</div>
<div class="memory-card" id="4">
    <img src="../assets/turned.png" class="front-face">
</div>
<div class="memory-card" id="5">
    <img src="../assets/turned.png" class="front-face">
</div>
<div class="memory-card" id="5">
    <img src="../assets/turned.png" class="front-face">
</div>
<div class="memory-card" id="6">
     <img src="../assets/turned.png" class="front-face">
</div>
<div class="memory-card" id="6">
     <img src="../assets/turned.png" class="front-face">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not really following what you're trying to accomplish, but have you looked at Splice for removing a random element from your array? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?  When you use `splice()`, the deleted element(s) are returned, so you can save them into a variable for use later.  `let removedItem = ids.splice(randomValue, 1);`

Comment: [*Array.prototype.pop*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) removes the last element from an array, it doesn't take any arguments. What you're looking for is [*Array.prototype.splice*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), which removes an element at a particular index.

Comment: `x` will *not* always be `-1` with that code, although it will be quite a large proportion of the time. This is because you're trying to find the index in that array of a randomly-selected index from that array - the indices go from 0 to 11 and only `"1"` to `"6"` are present in the array. (I also have no idea why you are storing them as strings rather than numbers.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond, actually that is not what is happening with OP's code, the problem is not that the value of x is -1, the problem is that OP is using Array.prototype.pop( ) function. This function always removes the last function from the array. The OP did not know this so they assumed that the value of 'x' was always -1 and that is why the last element was being removed.

Comment: @Link - fair point, I only looked at how `x` was being calculated, and since that was clearly wrong, as well as what the OP was drawing attention to, I didn't see the need to look further before making my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will help you understand your existing code and where you are going wrong with it:

> You don't need to get ids.indexOf(rand) here, the reason is because
> Math.Random is going to generate a number between 0 and 1 and then you
> are multiplying it with ids.length. Which means, the value of
> Math.random() will start from 0 and may go upto ids.length. Because
> your array is 0 based too, you can directly use this value and pass it
> as a parameter into the function you will use in order to split the
> array.

```
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * ids.length); 
    let x = ids.indexOf(rand.toString());
```

> Array.prototype.pop( ) function always removes the last element of the
> array and returns it's value. That is the reason why you are always
> getting the last element.

```
    ids.pop(ids[x]);
```

What you can use instead is **Array.prototype.splice()**. What this function does, is it takes in 2 arguments - start index and end index, and it mutates the array, which means it will alter your original array. Also, it returns the value of the removed element in a new array.

I have added a snippet example of that below, you should run it and see the results, also it is a good idea to copy this code to your own IDE and try to debug it using console.log( ) to log values at every step and see what is happening to get a better understanding. Feel free to ask any queries in the comments below this question.

```js
let ids = ["1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6"];

function idHandler() {
    const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * ids.length);
    const x = ids.splice(rand, 1)[0]; 
    //[0] in above line to return the removed element instead of an array 
    //containing the element
    console.log(x);
    console.log(ids);
}

idHandler();
```

Comment: This helped very much but now it can't identify `cards[x]` which is very weird imo. Maybe you know why this is but I will try to fix this myself for now. What i changed is this
`
function mapIds() {
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * ids.length)
    let x = ids.indexOf(rand.toString())
    console.log(x)
    let removedId = ids.splice(rand, 1)
    ids.splice(x, 1)
    console.log(ids)
    cards[removedId[0]].setAttribute("id", removedId[0])
} 
`

Comment: can you try to do this and see what gets printed to the console - console.log(cards[x]);

Comment: cards variable as per the code you shared in the question is a Node List which has all the DOM Nodes which correspond to the class '.memory-card'. Can you update the question and show me all the elements in your HTML with the class '.memory-card' maybe I will be able to help with that info.

Comment: sometimes it outputs my html div and other times just undefined

Comment: document.QuerySelectorAll( ) returns a node list, which is like a list of all nodes with which are of the class '.memory-card' in your case. When the value is a div element, it means that there is an element corresponding to that value of 'x'. When it is undefined, it means that there is no DOM element in the node list at that particular value of 'x'. You  might need to make HTML changes/fixes to resolve this issue.

Comment: I thought that `[x]` signifies the index of an element in an array. But anyway, the updated code above now outputs the right stuff in the console but I have two sets of three times the same card

Comment: [x] does signify the index of an element in an array. But in this case the 'cards'  is not an array, instead it is a DOM Nodelist (which has some similarities to an array). So when you do cards[x], it will try to retrieve the xth element of the Nodelist. But it gives you undefined when there is no xth element of that nodelist.

Comment: I understand why nothing was working now. Thanks for the help and i will look into nodeLists myself tomorrow since it's alredy very late were I live

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access the array incorrectly,

```
function idHandler() {
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * ids.length);
    let x = ids[rand]
    ids.splice(rand,1) // can use this to remove an index from array
    cards[rand].setAttribute("id", x); // values should already be strings as they are stored with "" marks
}
```

You can actually skip a step if you don't need to use the variable `x` again

```
function idHandler() {
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * ids.length);
    cards[rand].setAttribute("id", ids[rand]); // values should already be strings as they are stored with "" marks
    ids.splice(rand,1) // can use this to remove an index from array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `splice` like so:

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".memory-card");

let ids = ["1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6"];

function idHandler() {
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * ids.length);
    let x = ids.indexOf(rand.toString());
    var removedIds = ids.splice(ids[x], 1);
    cards[x].setAttribute("id", removedIds[0]);
}

cards.forEach(mapIds);
```

The function splice() removes elements from an array at the given position and returns the elements as array.

More info here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice